# SpriteKit OS X get which key was pressed

Tags: macos, sprite-kit

In an OS X sprite kit project I can implement the `keyDown(_:)` and `keyUp(_:)` methods to listen for key events. How do I find which key was pressed (up arrow, A, 2, space, etc). I can use the `characters` property for alphabetical keys but how do I check for arrow or space keys. Can I use the `keyCode` property and will this be different/likely to change with keyboard/mac type.

Comment: Yes, used keyCode and only keyCode. This guarantees that users have to press the same button on the keyboard, regardless of what letter is printed on that key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the game. If you're developing a game where the characters have meaning (for example, a game where a=attack, p=pause, g=throw grenade), then processing the `theEvent.characters` makes sense. If you use key codes and the user uses a different keyboard layout (e.g., Dvorak, Colmak), the user would be forced to mentally remap the keys to the QWERTY keyboard layout.

Here's an example of how to convert characters in `theEvent.characters` to a UTF-16 representation. It's useful to detect if special characters, such as the up/down arrows, were pressed.

```
override func keyDown(theEvent:NSEvent) {
    for codeUnit in theEvent.characters!.utf16 {
        println ("Keypressed: \(codeUnit)")
    }
}
```

For other types of games where the location of the keys matter (for example W = up, A = left, D = right, S = down), using the hardware-independent key code property makes more sense.

Comment: In game apps one should always use the keyCode, not the character. Otherwise users of different locale may end up having to press Shift or Ctrl to create a character that would otherwise be a single keypress for other locales. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/keyCode